# EF 4.1: Replacing a child entity before inserting the parent

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

When I try to insert an entity that had a child that I replaced by another child, I'm getting an error message.

Here are the details:

I have a one-to-many relationship where the child element sometimes needs to be inserted and other times it needs to be updated. This is concerning an ASP.Net MVC 3 project using EF 4.1.

Here is an example to illustrate what I am trying to do. Let's say I have these 2 objects:

```
public class Foo {
    [Key]
    public int FooId { get; set; } 
    public int BarId { get; set; } 
    public Bar bar { get; set; } 
    public string type;
}

public class Bar {
    [Key]
    public int BarId { get; set; } 
    public string name;
    public string email;
}
```

And I have a form to create a new Foo having these 3 fiels:

1. Type
2. Name
3. Email

Now, before saving Foo, I check whether Bar already exists in my database using the email field, since I don't want to have two Bars with the same email. If there is no Bar with the given email, everything is fine and I save Foo, which creates a new Foo and a new Bar in the the database. However, if I find an existing Bar in the database, I do the following:

```
existingBar.Name = myFoo.Bar.Name;    //To update the name
myFoo.Bar = existingBar;              //Replace the Bar that was going to be inserted with Foo by the existing one
fooRepository.Add(myFoo);
SaveFoo();
```

When I do this however, I get the following error message:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

I also tried this:

```
existingBar.Name = myFoo.Bar.Name;    //To update the name
ModelCopier.CopyModel(existingBar, myFoo.Bar);
fooRepository.Add(myFoo);
SaveFoo();
```

In this case, I am getting the following error message:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

So, is there a way save myFoo with an existing Bar as child?

Comment: "*I have a one-to-many relationship where the child element sometimes needs to be inserted and other times it needs to be updated.*" From your further description I must assume that `Bar` is the child. But then it makes no sense that the parent `Foo` has a single reference and a foreign key to `Bar` if you have a one-to-many relationship between the parent `Foo` (one) and the child(ren) `Bar` (many). So, also the exception is very weird for such a model. Can you make your relationships more precise?

Comment: @Slauma Maybe my wording was wrong, but I meant that a Bar can have many Foos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling barRepository.update(existingBar) after modifying it? THEN attempt to add your new Foo.

Comment: Thanks Jack! Your suggestion put me on the right track. This will need more testing to make sure it is working fine, but copying the fields one by one instead of using ModelCopier.CopyModel() and saving existingBar beforehand seems to be the solution.